# C# WPF: Removing items received in ListView.Selecteditems from list

Tags: c#, listview, casting

I have a class Book and List. I'm using ListView to display my list and I want to remove selected items on button press. 
This is my approach:

```
private void currentlyReadingRemoveItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedItems = CurrentlyReadingBooksListView.SelectedItems;
        _currentlyReadingBooks.Except((List<Book>)selectedItems);
    }
```

However, I get this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BookshelfLibrary.Book]'.'

I have been trying to solve this for past hour, I tried some other casting methods and I don't even know what else, I'm too tired to think. 
This is entire project: https://github.com/GoldenDragonPC/Bookshelf

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: 
Working code.

```
            var selectedItems = CurrentlyReadingBooksListView.SelectedItems;
        var test = _currentlyReadingBooks.Except(selectedItems.Cast<Book>());
        _currentlyReadingBooks = test.ToList();
        WriteData(_currentlyReadingBooks, CurrentlyReadingPath);
        InitializeList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using linq's cast method. Something like:

```
_currentlyReadingBooks.Except(selectedItems.Cast<Book>()?.ToList());
```

**Update**

```
_currentlyReadingBooks = _currentlyReadingBooks.Except(selectedItems.Cast<Book>()).ToList();
```

Comment: Also, make sure you do something with the return value.  `Except` doesn't work in-place, it returns an IEnumerable.

Comment: Thanks, but while this doesn't throw any errors it doesn't actually remove items from list for some reason. I just saw that I need to do something with return variable, will try it in a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you guys, figured it out.